# PVC status is stuck on pending and PV status is available

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc

I was trying to increase the PVC size from 10G to 20G, since we are running on 1.9.3 doing it online is not there. So i have deleted the PVC and created with new value of 20G as storage.

```
pvc-b196868cd-bc75-12e8-ad32-075738325c   100Gi      RWO            Retain           Released    myapp/myapp-backup-pv-claim`                                persistent                   4m
```

As i deleted, the PV status turned on to "Released" and when i tried to recreate the PVC the it got created but with the status "lost"

```
myapp-myapp-backup-pv-claim                 Lost      pvc-03b34iknca1-6fr3-19ea-af3b-0073yh2u97f   0                         ntfts19-k8s-0101   13m
```

We are using the Vsphere volumes. Tried the solution of "kubectl patch pv pv-for-rabbitmq -p '{"spec":{"claimRef": null}}'" this helped me to bring back the pv in "Available" status, now the PVC is in stuck with "Pending" state.

```
pvc-b196868cd-bc75-12e8-ad32-075738325c   100Gi      RWO            Retain           Available    myapp/myapp-backup-pv-claim`                                persistent                   2m

myapp-myapp-backup-pv-claim                 Pending      pvc-03b34iknca1-6fr3-19ea-af3b-0073yh2u97f   0                         ntfts19-k8s-0101   28m
```

PV Describe:

```
Name:          myapp-myapp-backup-pv-claim   
Namespace:     myapp
StorageClass:  ntfts19-k8s-0101 
Status:        Pending
Volume:        pvc-03b34iknca1-6fr3-19ea-af3b-0073yh2u97f 
Labels:        app=my-app
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    []
Capacity:      0
Access Modes:
Events:        <none>
```

PVC Describe:

```
Name:            pvc-b196868cd-bc75-12e8-ad32-075738325c
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     <none>
StorageClass:    persistent
Status:          Available
Claim:           myapp/myapp-backup-pv-claim
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
Capacity:        100Gi
Message:
Source:
    Type:        vSphereVolume (a Persistent Disk resource in vSphere)
    VolumePath:      StoragePolicyName:  %v

    FSType:                            [dsNTFTS19_0101] kubevols/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-b196868cd-bc75-12e8-ad32-075738325c.vmdk
%!(EXTRA string=ext4, string=)Events:  <none>
```

Comment: Could you please paste the output of kubectl describe <<persistent-volume>> and kubectl describe <<persistent-volume-claim>>

Comment: Described the pv and pvc but now its an different issue so i have changed the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was not having annotations, since this is a VSphere storage the annotation `volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner=kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume` is a mandatory one.

Answer (score 1):

The storage class for PV and PVC should be same. The control plane can only bind PVC with PV only if it can find the PV with same storage class.

You PV has `storageClass: ntfts19-k8s-0101` and your PVC has `storageClass: persistent`. So control plane couldn't find a matching PV that has storageClass persistent.

Delete and recreate the PVC to match the storage class of the PV.

Please refer the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/)

Comment: I changed the PVC storage class to `ntfts19-k8s-0101` but it didn't fix the issue its still in pending state. Also i tried changing both of them to persistent storage class as well but no luck.

Comment: Could you update your access modes as well to match the PV?

Comment: Both access modes are already set to 'ReadWriteOnce' but while describing the pvc it doesn't show any access modes.